How to set AppKit (Web3Modal) provider for web3.js?
Dear smart contract front-end developers,
As you know, AppKit is the new verion of Web3Modal. I am using it in a web javascript program to show a dialog to connect the web page to the desired wallet. Then I want to use Web3.js to interact with some smart contracts.
So I use this program:
import { createAppKit } from '@reown/appkit';
import { bsc } from '@reown/appkit/networks';
import { WagmiAdapter } from '@reown/appkit-adapter-wagmi';
import { reconnect } from '@wagmi/core';
import { Web3 } from 'web3';

const projectId = '...';
const networkList = [ bsc];
const wagmiAdapter = new WagmiAdapter({
    projectId,
    networks: networkList
});
const metadata = {
    name: '...',
    description: '...',
    url: 'https://...',
    icons: ['...'],
};
const modal = createAppKit({
    adapters: [wagmiAdapter],
    networks: networkList,
    projectId,
    metadata: metadata,
    themeMode: 'light'
});
reconnect(wagmiAdapter.wagmiConfig);
const web3 = new Web3(xxx);

Now I want to use a Web3 provider instead of xxx in the last line of the above program.
For example if I use window.ethereum it works only if I use Metamask wallet.
What can I use instead of Web3 provider so it connects to the wallet that selected in AppKit modal dialog?
I will appreciate you, even if you give a solution in Web3Modal.

You don't need web3. You are using the wagmi adapter, from now on you can just call wagmi itself:
import { useReadContract } from 'wagmi'
import { USDTAbi } from '../abi/USDTAbi'

const USDTAddress = '0x...'

function App() {
  const result = useReadContract({
    abi: USDTAbi,
    address: USDTAddress,
    functionName: 'totalSupply'
  })
}

Make sure that the adapter and the context is set correctly, for more info you can check:
https://docs.reown.com/appkit/next/core/installation

Based on AppKit docs we need to use Next.js or React.js for using Wagmi.
I need pure javascript. So I used Wb3.js.

Then you should not use the adapters for wagmi, what's your current state?

Can you suggest another adapter?
I used it as Appkit suggested it.
